# Can I use namespaces with restler?

Tags: php, restler

I'm using the restler library from Luracast and I would like to use namespaces for my API classes. As an example, can I do:

```
$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('\fully\qualified\path\Foo');
$r->handle();
```

At present it's throwing an error on line 340 in restler.php:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Foo' not found in /work/projects/xxxx/lib/Restler/restler/restler.php on line 341
```

Right now I have conflicting class names and I'd like to use namespaces rather than hack around the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restler did not support namespaces until now!

We have just added namespaces support to [Restler 2.1.7](https://github.com/Luracast/Restler/commit/987b4fe0c3673d5cd9d447e372ea501c16e0bdb8) and released it just now

```
$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('fully\qualified\path\Foo');
$r->handle();
```

should work fine now :)

Comment: Awesome. I was about to start working on a patch but clearly you were WAY ahead of me. Thanks for the update -- so far I'm really enjoying the restler framework. Going to update to the latest version now.